# (Clojure) Count how many times any character appear in a string

Tags: clojure, pattern-matching, character, string-matching, clojure-repl

I am trying to write a function (char-count) which takes a pattern and a string, then returns a number (count) which represents how many times any of the characters in the pattern appear in the string.

For example:

`(char-count "Bb" "Best buy")`

would return `2` since there is 1 match for `B` and 1 match for `b`, so added together we get `2`

`(char-count "AaR" "A Tale of Recursion")`

would return `3` and so on

---

I tried using `re-seq` in my function, but it seems to work only for continuous strings. As in `(re-seq #Bb "Best Buy)` only looks for the pattern `Bb`, not for each individual character.

This is what my function looks like so far:

```
(defn char-count [pattern text]
  (count (re-seq (#(pattern)) text)))
```

But it does not do what I want. Can anybody help?

P.s. Very new to clojure (and functional programming in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the characters in `[...]` within the RegEx:

```clj
(count (re-seq #"[Bb]" "Best buy"))
```

Or, since you need that pattern to be dynamic:

```clj
(count (re-seq (re-pattern (str "[" pattern "]")) text))
```

But note that the solution might not work properly if the pattern contains special RegEx characters such as `[`, `]`, `\`, `-`, `^` - you'd have to escape them by prepending `\\` in front of each one.

Comment: `Pattern/quote` is the recommended way to quote patterns, not ad hoc code to put `\\` characters in front of stuff by hand.

Comment: Depends on whom you ask, I suppose. `Pattern/quote` would work, but then you'd have to split the pattern into characters, escape every character, build a group for each, combine those groups with `|`. Whereas the set of metachars is well known.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need anything nearly as powerful as a regular expression here, so just use the simple tools your programming language comes with: sets and functions. Build a set of the characters you want to find, and count how many characters from the input string are in the set.

```
(defn char-count [chars s]
  (count (filter (set chars) s)))
```